# How to separate the model into two applications

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

I have one application and one model.
I want to separate the model on two applications, so that the user was managed from a separate application.
Is the transfer of this model will do the trick? What I have to do?

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    country = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=COUNTRY, default=RUSSIA)
```

Here is my models.py - must be separate

```
RUSSIA = 'RUS'
USA = 'USA'
GERMANY = 'GER'


COUNTRY = (
    (RUSSIA, "Russia"),
    (USA, "USA"),
    (GERMANY, "Germany"),
)

class User(AbstractUser):

    country = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=COUNTRY, default=RUSSIA)


class Country(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRY, default=RUSSIA)
    name_of_team = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_of_team
```

Comment: Do you mean to have two application with two models(one for user and one for country)?

Comment: @Andres I have one application with two models. I want to have two separate applications and model of the first applications between these applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two applications, one for Users and one for Countries. Then put the User model in the Users app and the Country model in the Countries app.

Then in a third app you can import both as you need them:

```
from countries.models import Country
from users.models import User
```

Put this part of the code in the settings.py file:

```
RUSSIA = 'RUS'
USA = 'USA'
GERMANY = 'GER'


COUNTRY = (
    (RUSSIA, "Russia"),
    (USA, "USA"),
    (GERMANY, "Germany"),
)
```

If you do this then you can access the constants from both apps like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.COUNTRY
```

Comment: Thanks :) please tell me how after creating several applications to migrate the database? when performed python manage.py makemigrations my_new_app, I get the error: "LookupError: App 'my_new_app' does not have a 'user' model."

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://django-authtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how-to/migrate-to-a-custom-user-model.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create two apps, one for users and one for countries, then you just  import country model into user model.

Besides if you want to keep a relationship between countries and user you should use a **ForeignKey**. Sorry if it does not match with your logic but I'm not sure how your models have to looks like, it is a bit estrange for me.

Something like this:

country/models.py

```
RUSSIA = 'RUS'
USA = 'USA'
GERMANY = 'GER'

COUNTRY = (
    (RUSSIA, "Russia"),
    (USA, "USA"),
    (GERMANY, "Germany"),
)


class Country(models.Model):
    # I don't know why country attr in Country class
    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRY, default=RUSSIA)
    name_of_team = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_of_team
```

user/models.py

```
from country.models import Country

class User(AbstractUser):
    # ForeignKey, here you make the relation with country model
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

Comment: When I want to make python manage.py makemigration my_new_app I get error: ImportError: No module named my_new_app.models - I make import in my models with Country

Comment: what's your app name? replace my_new_app with your app name

Comment: OK, it is ok now but please tell me how after creating several applications to migrate the database? when performed python manage.py makemigrations my_new_app, I get the error: "LookupError: App 'my_new_app' does not have a 'user' model.